# Faceting with Django Rest Framwork / Django Filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Dear fellow overflowers,

I’m currently building an API based on Django Rest Framework with Django Filter.

Search, filtering and sorting works reasonably well, though I was wondering about filter facets.

Imagine there’s a “Person” model and you’d like to allow users to filter by the first letter peoples’ names. You don’t want users to run into a “no results” situation, so you only want to suggest the letters that match at least one person.

What is a good way to provide a list of choices (the facets) for each filter?
Does it make sense to use a different endpoint that provides choices only?
To me, it would feel right to declare facets inside the FilterSet subclass, because it’s the place where anything filter-related happens.

Looking forward to your comments!

Julian

PS: Typically, I use ElasticSearch in situations like this, but I wonder if there’s an idiomatic solution in plain DRF/DF.

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


# filters
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from django.db.models.functions import Substr


def get_first_letter_choices():
    # Create choices
    letters = Person.objects \
        .all() \
        .annotate(first_letter=Substr('name', 1, 1)) \
        .values_list("first_letter", flat=True) \
        .distinct()
        
    return [(letter, letter, ) for letter in letters]

class PersonFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    first_letter = filters.ChoiceFilter(
        choices=get_first_letter_choices,
        field_name="name",
        lookup_expr="startswith"
    )

# DRF Views/Serializers
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ["name", ]


# views.py
from rest_framework import ListAPIView

class PersonsIndex(ListAPIView):
    filterset_class = PersonFilterSet
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Person.objects.all()
```

I tried using a different endpoint and using a custom serializer that would include choice fields, but it feels like I’m fighting DRF/DF.